# Unit test can't see the library used in tested code

Tags: swift, unit-testing, cocoapods

I'm trying to set up the unit tests to test the functionality. The main project is the workspace with 2 project: main project and pods (Alamofire is currently in use, installed with Cocoapods).

The main project has Utils.swift class that uses Alamofire to do http request. It works perfect.

Also I added unit test swift file and then created a new target in the main project that tests this Utils class.

I added Utils.swift to the "Compile resources" of the test project target else it wouldn't see the main project.

The test class sees Utils class now but when I try to run test that calls function from Utils (that uses Alamofire) it shows the error "No such module Alamofire". I don't know how to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. It turned out that if you create one more target that uses pod (even indirectly) you need to add one more record into Podfile:

```
target 'TestProject' do

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

end
```